# Output of transformer

Tags: transformer

Does the per unit change in voltage   on secondary of a transformer depend only on the power factor of load and not the value/magnitude of load connected across the secondary?

Comment: The power factor of the load is part of the value of the load. What about source impedance?

Comment: By value of load I meant like 200angle 36.86 lag(inductive load) and 200 angle 0(resistive load) and supply to be purely resistive (angle 0)

Comment: It depends on all the load including the real component of load impedance. So, No.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to define what you mean by voltage regulation? I think a lot of people are confused by this at the moment and not understanding your question. But the secondary voltage will change as the load resistance changes. So it depends on value of load as well as power factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... if you connect a load whose impedance is entirely imaginary, it still draws current and you can be sure that the transformer will see that as a load.

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Unfortunately no T_T

Comment: Would you like to rephrase the question in that case to make it clearer ?

Comment: OK, you seem to be asking if the magnitude of the load (W) has no effect on regulation whereas load (VA) does do so ? The answer is NO btw. How did you get this idea ?

Comment: Actually when i just saw the formula of voltage regulation of transformer
   Which was 

Regulation=Xeq(perUnit)sin phi+Req(perUnit) cos phi 
Where Req+ j Xeq is the net leakage impedance of transformer armatures
phi is power factor on load side
So i wondered the magnitude of load shouldn't matter

Comment: Where did you get that equation for regulation ? It looks wrong to me.

Comment: https://electricalbaba.com/voltage-regulation-of-a-transformer/#:~:text=Voltage%20Regulation%20of%20Transformer%20is,maintain%20the%20Primary%20Voltage%20constant.&text=2%20in%20pu-,%3D%20(E2%E2%80%93%20V2),x100%20%2F%20E2%20in%20percentage.

Comment: Your link  ..... ' Voltage Regulation of Transformer is defined as change in magnitude of Secondary Terminal Voltage per unit Rated Secondary Terminal Voltage when load at a given Power Factor is reduced to zero while maintain the Primary Voltage constant'.  ...... This is a long winded definition and not particularly correct ! Let's reduce it somewhat, No need to mention the primary voltage. Omit Terminals and 'per unit'. that leaves .....  'Transformer Regulation is change in magnitude of Secondary Voltage when (the) load at a given Power Factor is reduced to zero.'  .... which is wrong !

Comment: Could you provide a link to the correction definition?

Answer (score 0):

There's no voltage regulation in a (normal) transformer; voltage regulation would imply the voltage wasn't primarily load-dependent, but it is. A transformer has a (complex) source impedance, and so has the source it's connected to, and you can pretty directly see how that's not a regulated system.

You'll need to do very specific things to incorporate regulation into a transformer; [wikipedia "voltage regulator" has a section on AC voltage regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator#AC_voltage_stabilizers), and your transformer isn't a regulator.

Comment: Voltage regulation in transformer is:    
Regulation=Xeq(perUnit) sin phi + Req(per Unit)cos phi
cos phi is power factor

Since per Unit values will be constant wrt change in magnitude of load .Does that mean regulation percentage will remain constant if only load's magnitude is changed such that power factor is not disturbed?

Comment: um, that's not what the word "regulation" means? (also, I really don't understand the way you wrote that formula: what's "Xeq", what's "per unit"?)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-%E2%80%9Cvoltage-regulation%E2%80%9D-in-a-transformer
Sorry for the confusion 
I have read the same formula in my classes as well
Per unit value of transformer is when say impedance is divided by rated impedance of transformer and so on with rest quantities
Xeq refers to the total inductance of the armatures and Req refers to the net resistance of armatures

Comment: @MarcusMüller This may be a language thing, but the word "regulation", in a transformer specification, indicates the extent to which the voltage is load dependent. A transformer with 5% regulation is better than one with 10% regulation : both normally measured open circuit and at rated load.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ah, thanks!